# insert into table select variable from table2 equivalent in mongodb

Tags: mysql, mongodb, insert

I was searching in Internet but I found nothing.
I want to know if there is an equivalent in mongodb for this mysql command:

```
insert into table1 select variables from table2;
```

what i want to do is to select a document and insert it to another document as it's subdocument.

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this in a single database command.

Whether you do this in the shell or in your scripting language of choice using a MongoDB driver, you will have to query for the document from collection1 and then do an appropriate update for collection2 using result from the query.

For example:

```
var doc = db.coll1.findOne( {_id:12345} );
db.coll2.update( {_id:98765}, {$push: {subs:doc} }, {upsert:1} )
```

What the update says is for document matching first argument do update in second argument (push into subs array value that's in doc) and last argument says create this document if it does not already exist (i.e. if _id: 98765 isn't already in collection2 it will be created).